# Is it more difficult to cut a single steel column, or a wire of the same width made up of several skinnier, individual wires?

Tags: structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering

Would it be more difficult to cut a single 15.75" column of solid galvanized steel, or a 15.75" wire made up of 5,282 individual strands, or would it be the same? The wire in question is the main cable to the [Brooklyn Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooklyn_Bridge). The only information I can find regarding this question is my old Army field manual FM 3-34.214, and the biggest cables it goes up to are 8", and it makes no difference between solid cables or composite cables. There is not much on the Internet regarding this. Most information I can find regarding explosives calculations are regarding quarry work. Examples can be found found in the [Pennsylvania Blaster's License Training Manual](http://www.depgreenport.state.pa.us/elibrary/PDFProvider.ashx?action=PDFStream&docID=5044&chksum=&revision=0&docName=5600-MN-DEP4778.pdf&nativeExt=pdf&PromptToSave=False&Size=540982&ViewerMode=2&overlay=0), or the [National Park Service Handbook for the Storage, Transportation, and Use of Explosives](https://www.nps.gov/parkhistory/online_books/npsg/explosives/contents.htm).

The information I find regarding specifically steel cutting charges is all old Army information. For example [FM 5-250](https://www.bits.de/NRANEU/others/amd-us-archive/fm5-250%2892%29.pdf) precedes the manual I have, and [other Army manuals](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/tr/pdf/AD0479244.pdf) date back even further. None of them address this specific question. While this may suggest that it does not matter whether you're cutting a steel column or a composite cable, it could also be the Army simply calculated for the more difficult one and left it simplified. So, I am not sure. Can anyone provide some clarity?

Comment: This question is probably being monitored by the FBI

Comment: I already explained on another question why this is not a security risk do I need to do that here, as well? Also, I am entirely unconcerned about the FBI, NSA, DIA, or whoever monitoring me. I was a combat engineer for 8 years of my life, I am fascinated by explosives, and there are not a lot of answers out there for questions like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would it take to explosively cut a 16" (15.75") steel cable?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56545/what-would-it-take-to-explosively-cut-a-16-15-75-steel-cable)

Comment: In another of your questions you claim layman but now combat engineer…

Comment: @SolarMike I would still consider combat engineers as laymen with explosives. Our direct training is rather minimal, only a few months. For example, I was never trained on steel-cutting charges, I simply read that from one of my manuals. So, yes, I was a combat engineer, and yes when it comes to explosives, I am a layman. Don't get me wrong, I could build a passable IED, and perform all the CE tasks and much more, but it is NOTHING like the experience I am seeking here (graduate degrees and professional experience).

Answer (score 0):

Practical experience in cutting bicycle locks was that it was more difficult to cut multi-strand wires than equivalent single-strand wires.

Because the strands shifted under the blade of the wire cutter, in such a way as to minimize the peak load.

Perhaps not specifically relevant to bridge design, because a bicycle lock is typically not in tension when cut.